Prove independence of events given random variables are iid and have (not absolutely) continuous cdf
Let $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ be independent and identically distributed random variables in $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ s.t. their distributions are continuous and $$F_Y(y) := F_{Y_1}(y) = F_{Y_2}(y) = \cdots$$
For $m = 1, 2, \ldots $ and $i \le m$, define $$A_{i,m} := (\max\{Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_m\} = Y_i), B_m := A_{m,m}$$

It can be shown that (or see here) $$P(B_m) = P(A_{m-1,m}) = \cdots = P(A_{2,m}) = P(A_{1,m}) = 1/m$$

To rigorously establish independence of the $B_m$:
I show that $\forall m \in \mathbb N$,
$$P(B_m\mid\sigma(B_1, \ldots, B_{m-1})) = P(B_m)$$
then we will have independence of the $B_m$'s.
I tried induction: Given $P(B_k\mid\sigma(B_1, \ldots, B_{k-1})) = 1/k$, prove
$$P(B_{k+1}\mid\sigma(B_1, \ldots, B_k))$$
I deduced that that is equivalent to:
Given $P(B_k \cap C_k) = P(C_k)(1/k)$, prove
$$P(B_{k+1} \cap C_{k+1}) = P(C_{k+1}) (1/(k+1))$$
where $C_k \in \sigma(B_1, \ldots, B_{k-1})$ and $C_{k+1} \in \sigma(B_1, \ldots, B_{k})$.
It seems that in proving $P(B_{k+1} \cap C_{k+1}) = P(C_{k+1}) (1/(k+1))$, we need to check only $C_{k+1} \in \sigma(B_{k})$ as $C_{k+1} \in \sigma(B_1, \ldots, B_{k-1})$ are already covered by assumption.

So all I have to do is show that $P(B_{k+1} \cap B_k) = (1/(k)(k+1))$ and $P(B_{k+1} \cap B_k^C) = (k-1)/(k)(k+1)$, the latter of w/c can be deduced from the former, which is proven by noting that
$$P(B_{k+1} \cap B_k) := P(Y_k > Y_1, \dots Y_{k-1}; Y_{k+1} > Y_1, \dots Y_{k-1}, Y_k) = P(Y_k > Y_1, \dots Y_{k-1}; Y_{k+1} > Y_k)$$
and then making use of the iid of the $Y_n$'s and evaluating:
Case1 - If they have pdfs i.e. are absolutely continuous
$$P(B_{k+1} \cap B_k) = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{-\infty}^{y_{k+1}} \int_{-\infty}^{y_k} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{y_k} \int_{-\infty}^{y_k} f(y_1)f(y_2) \cdots f(y_{k-1})f(y_k)f(y_{k+1}) \, dy_1 \, dy_2 \cdots dy_{k-1} \, dy_k \, dy_{k+1}$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{-\infty}^{y_{k+1}} [F(y_k)]^{k-1} f(y_k) f(y_{k+1}) \, dy_k \, dy_{k+1}$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{(F(y_{k+1}))^{k}}{k} f(y_{k+1}) dy_{k+1} = \frac{1}{(k)(k+1)}$$
Case2 - Even if the pdfs don't exist, can I actually still evaluate the same way?
I mean, it's still $u=F(y_k)$ but then instead of $du=f(y_k)dy_k$, it's $du=dF(y_k)$.
Word-for-word, I think:
$$P(B_{k+1} \cap B_k) = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{-\infty}^{y_{k+1}} \int_{-\infty}^{y_k} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{y_k} \int_{-\infty}^{y_k} \, dF(y_1) \, dF(y_2) \cdots dF(y_{k-1}) \, dF(y_k)\,dF(y_{k+1})$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{-\infty}^{y_{k+1}} [F(y_k)]^{k-1} dF(y_k) dF(y_{k+1})$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{(F(y_{k+1}))^{k}}{k} dF(y_{k+1}) = \frac{1}{(k)(k+1)}$$

If you have issues with my answer please let me know! :)

If $y\mapsto F_Y(y)$ is continuous and $Y$ has df $F_Y$, then $F_Y(Y)\sim U[0,1]$. Let ${Y}_m^*:=\max(Y_1,...,Y_m)$ where $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are IID with continuous cdf $F_Y$. Then for $m\geq 2$
$$\begin{aligned}
P({Y}_m^*={Y}_m)&=P({Y}_{m-1}^*\leq {Y}_m)\\
&=E[P({Y}_{m-1}^*\leq {Y}_m|Y_m)]\\
&=E[P({Y}_{m-1}^*\leq x)|_{x=Y_m}]\\
&=E[(F_Y(Y_m))^{m-1}]\\
&=E[U^{m-1}]\\
&=1/m
\end{aligned}$$
We have
$$\begin{aligned}
P({Y}_m^*={Y}_m,{Y}_{m-1}^*={Y}_{m-1})&=P({Y}_{m-1}^*\leq{Y}_m,{Y}_{m-1}^*={Y}_{m-1})\\
&=P({Y}_{m-1}\leq{Y}_m,{Y}_{m-1}^*={Y}_{m-1})\\
&=P({Y}_{m-1}\leq{Y}_m,{Y}_{m-2}^*\leq {Y}_{m-1})\\
&=E[P({Y}_{m-1}\leq{Y}_m,{Y}_{m-2}^*\leq {Y}_{m-1}|Y_m)]\\
&=E[P({Y}_{m-1}\leq x,{Y}_{m-2}^*\leq {Y}_{m-1})|_{x=Y_m}]\\
&=E[E[\mathbf{1}_{\{{Y}_{m-1}\leq x\}}P({Y}_{m-2}^*\leq Y_{m-1}|Y_{m-1})]|_{x=Y_m}]\\
&=E[E[\mathbf{1}_{\{{Y}_{m-1}\leq x\}}P({Y}_{m-2}^*\leq z)|_{z={Y}_{m-1}}]|_{x=Y_m}]\\
&=E[E[\mathbf{1}_{\{{Y}_{m-1}\leq x\}}(F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))^{m-2}]|_{x=Y_m}]\\
&=E[E[\mathbf{1}_{\{{Y}_{m-1}\leq Y_m\}}(F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))^{m-2}|Y_m]]\\
&=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{{Y}_{m-1}\leq Y_m\}}(F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))^{m-2}]\\
&=E[P({Y}_{m-1}\leq Y_m|Y_{m-1})(F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))^{m-2}]\\
&=E[P({Y}_{m}\geq y)|_{y=Y_{m-1}}(F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))^{m-2}]\\
&=E[(1-F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))(F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))^{m-2}]\\
&=E[F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))^{m-2}]-E[F_Y({Y}_{m-1}))^{m-1}]\\
&=E[U^{m-2}]-E[U^{m-1}]\\
&=1/(m-1)-1/m\\
&=1/(m(m-1))
\end{aligned}$$
We conclude.
